# execute mysql on remote server via bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I need to execute a mysql command on a remote server but seem to be hitting problem when it comes to executing the actual mysql bit

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -t root@10.0.0.2
expect "password: "
sleep 1
send "password\r"
sleep 2
/usr/bin/mysql databasename -e "update device_log set status = 'Y' where device_id in ('1','2');"
```

basically I want to change the flag to Y on device id's 1&2

but the script outputs

invalid command name "/usr/bin/mysql"

Answer (score 2):

Just append the `mysql` command to the `ssh` command to run it in one go, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -t root@10.0.0.2 /usr/bin/mysql databasename -e "the query"
expect "password: "
sleep 1
send "password\r"
```

I'm not very much into `expect`, but I'm expecting that your attempt in the `mysql` line isn't actually valid syntax for expect to run a command.

Additionally:

- You *should* use SSH keys for passwordless login instead of having a root password hardcoded in a script.
- Consider running MySQL remotely e.g. `mysql -h 10.0.0.2 -e "the query"`, or
- Use port forwarding in SSH to connect to MySQL securely, e.g. run `ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 root@10.0.0.2` in the background and then connect to TCP port 3307 on localhost `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307`.

Comment: doesn't work for some reason, outputs     ./log
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -t root@10.0.0.2 /usr/bin/mysql databasename -e "update device_log set status = 'Y' where device_id in ('1','2');"
root@10.0.00.2's password: root@box:/usr/local/sbin#

Comment: @Lurch That's good, right? `mysql` should *not* output anything if your query is successful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `/usr/bin/mysql` is not the the path to the `mysql` binary on that remote server. You could use just `mysql` instead, assuming that the binary is somewhere in that remote server's `PATH`. Otherwise you will have to go and find out where the binary is actually located and alter the absolute path accordingly.